# OffsetDateTime - print offset instead of Z

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time, timezone-offset

I have this code:

```
String date = "2019-04-22T00:00:00+02:00";

OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime
      .parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)                             
      .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+00:00"));

System.out.println(odt);
```

This print: `2019-04-21T22:00Z`

How can I print `2019-04-21T22:00+00:00`? With offset instead of `Z`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-

Answer (score 13, accepted):

None of the static `DateTimeFormatter`s do this in the standard library.
They either default to `Z` or `GMT`.

To achieve `+00:00` for no offset, you will have to build your own `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) // use the existing formatter for date time
        .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00") // set 'noOffsetText' to desired '+00:00'
        .toFormatter();

System.out.println(now.format(dateTimeFormatter)); // 2019-12-20T17:58:06.847274+00:00
```

Answer (score 7):

My version would be:

```
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx");

    String date = "2019-04-22T00:00:00+02:00";

    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime
          .parse(date)                             
          .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    System.out.println(odt.format(outputFormatter));
```

Output is the desired:

> 2019-04-21T22:00:00+00:00

When `toString()` gives output in an unwanted format, the answer is using a `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting into the desired format. Lowercase `xxx` in the format pattern string produces offset formatted in hours and minutes with a colon as shown, also when the offset is 0.

While `OffsetDateTime.toString()` doesn’t produce the format that you wanted, `OffsetDateTime` is still able to parse it without any explicit formatter. So in my version of the code I left it out.

There is a constant already declared for `ZoneOffset.of("+00:00")`, which I prefer to use: `ZoneOffset.UTC`.