# Java LocalDateTime: Why is Unsupported field: OffsetSeconds produced?

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse the below `processingdate` so that I can eventually end up with a date of format `2020-11-10T10:43:07+00:00`. How can I amend the below to produce this?

```
 String processingDate = "2020-11-24";
    LocalDateTime dt =
        LocalDateTime.of(
            LocalDate.parse(
                processingDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE),
            LocalTime.now());

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dt.format(formatter));
System.out.println(dateTime);

java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: OffsetSeconds
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A local datetime doesn't contain any concept of zones or offsets. You are trying to print the offset to a string by using `XXX` at the end of the pattern.

But anyway, there is no need to go from a LocalDateTime -> String -> OffsetDateTime.

Just do

```
dt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

or whatever other offset you want

Comment: Thanks for this, this now produces 2020-11-24T15:03:54Z , how can I produce this format 2020-11-10T10:43:07+00:00?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429419/offsetdatetime-print-offset-instead-of-z