# Timestamp behaving differently in local and deployable environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx, google-cloud-platform, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a spring boot application that uses the following method to parse a timestamp into my required format

```
public static String getDate(String input) {
    DateTimeFormatter parsePattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSXXXX");
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, parsePattern);
    Date o = Date.from(ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    return sdf.format(o);
}
```

Now when this code is executed in local machine the above method returns:

2021-08-11T09:00:02.237+05:30

But when i am deploying this to an environment running nginx server the above method returns:

2021-08-11T09:00:02.237Z

Now what my understanding is that it is getting converted to UTC format(+0000/Z). Please correct me if i am wrong. But the expected format is 2021-08-11T09:00:02.237+05:30 (Ignore +05:30. just want the time zone to come in this format instead of Z). How can i achieve that in environment ?

Comment: When you want a specific timezone, when don't rely on `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

Comment: @Tom thank you for your input. But i need the format to be lets say for UTC its going to be +00:00 or +0000. I don't want the Z

Comment: You can use `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")` instead of default.

Comment: @aksappy I don't want that time zone. I dont want my formatted string to have Z in it

Comment: What is `input`?

Comment: @g00se 2021-08-11T09:00:00.000000000Z, It will not matter as i am creating a localDateTime object but there you go

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429419/offsetdatetime-print-offset-instead-of-z) answer your question

Answer (score 0):

```
ZonedDateTime nowHere = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.systemDefault());
String timestamp = parsePattern.format(nowHere.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
```

Does that work for you?